# SQLDeveloper not able to handle empty dates?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a DB table export (.csv file generated using SQLDeveloper) that I need to import into another DB table.
The issue is that there are date columns that are nullable and these values are obviously exported as empty string. When I try to import that file then SQLDeveloper internally seems to generate an insert statement for each line since I get the below error message:

```
INSERT INTO <tablename> (<fieldnames here>) VALUES (... ,to_date('', 'DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS'), ...);
Error report -
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

In that insert SQLDeveloper apparently tries to convert the empty string into a date using to_date(...) which then obviously yields an error.

Is there some workaround, so allows to import such dates as 'null' into the DB? After all: it should somehow be feasible to import .csv files again that were generated by SQLDeveloper, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me.

Since you didn't provide table definition or sample data, I made up my own scenario. Compare what I did to what you're doing.

```
create table csv_null_dates (id integer, dates date);
insert into csv_null_dates values (1, sysdate);
insert into csv_null_dates values (2, sysdate-1);
insert into csv_null_dates values (3, sysdate+1);
insert into csv_null_dates values (4, null);
insert into csv_null_dates values (5, sysdate);

set sqlformat csv
cd c:\users\jdsmith\desktop
spool null_dates.csv
select * from csv_null_dates;
spool off
```

The output:

```
Table CSV_NULL_DATES created.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.


1 row inserted.

"ID","DATES"
1,26-SEP-19
2,25-SEP-19
3,27-SEP-19
4,
5,26-SEP-19
```

I then opened the table import wizard, and pointed to my CSV file:

[image]

I finished the wizard, import ran to completion, here's my log:

```
** Import Start ** at 2019.09.26-08.12.59
Import C:\Users\jdsmith\Desktop\null_dates.csv to HR.HR.CSV_NULL_DATES 
Load Method: Insert
** Import End ** at 2019.09.26-08.13.00
```

And when I go to browse my table, I see that I have 2x the records I had before, including the row with the NULL date:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeff - thanks a lot for testing this! Good to know that there seem to be a way to achieve this. l guess I will need to experiment with the export. Maybe the issue then was because I had specified to use quotes on all fields, or somethings of that sort.